# VIM: cycle through string

Tags: regex, vim, string

I'm trying to change in an url all text longer then 6 characters to 6characters~1 p.e.

c:\program files\vim directory\vim73\  to
c:\progra~1\vimdir~1\vim73

I have found a way to find the string length between "\ \"
strlen(matchstr("c:\program files\vim directory\vim73\","\\\zs.*\ze\\"))

but how can I cycle through a string?

How can I cut it to 6 characters (removing the spaces if there are) and put "~1" behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for your example text but I'm not sure it would work in all cases (assumes your filename is on it's own line, you could modify it to be more specific otherwise):

```
:s# ##ge|s#\v\\\zs(\w{6}).{-}\ze\\#\1\~1#&
```

Edit: just noticed that this leaves a trailing slash.  If you want that removed too you can use the following instead:

```
:s# ##ge|s#\v\\\zs(\w{6}).{-}\ze\\#\1\~1#&|s#\\$##&
```

Comment: I forgot to write that I have to put the output of this code in a variable (in a vimscript). How can I do this?

Comment: Use the `substitute()` function instead of the `:substitute` command.  See `:help substitute()` for more info.

Comment: No idea how to put your command in a substitute command. I tried this but it doesn't work: `substitute(m, "/ //ge|s/\v\\\zs(\w{6}).{-}\ze\\","\1\~1/&|s/\\$//&","g")`  ---> m = my string

Comment: Ah I've seen that there are 3 subst. commands: I created these but stil doesn't work:     `let r = substitute(m,' ','','ge')`   
    `let s = substitute(r,'\v\\\zs(\w{6}).{-}\ze\\','\1\~1/&','g')` 
    `let t = substitute(s,'\\$','/&','g')`

Comment: In the last two substitute calls get rid of the `/&`.  That is a shortcut for the `:s` command.  Also consider adding the `e` flag to those so it will not error out if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: @Randy, what would be the command if I only want to change the directories with spaces inside p.e. `c:\program files\vim\vimfiles`  program files --> progra~1 and leave vimfiles as it is? (I'm trying to adapt windows paths to unix paths).

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex should do the trick:

```
:%s /\\\([^\\]\{6\}\)[^\\]*/\\\1\~1\\/g
```

It essentially means: Match the first 6 characters between two occurences of `\` or one ocurrence of `\` and newline. Remember those characters (`\( ... \)` is used to remember) and match everything else until the separator (newline or `\`). Substitute that with the first 6 characters and `~1`.

Comment: This doesn't remove spaces and leaves extra `\\`s around, I believe.

Comment: @randy-morris: Right, i missed that the example included removing spaces. Re extra `\`: that shouldn't hurt i think. Maybe I am wrong with this?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what the use is after the transformation.

Comment: I forgot to write that I have to put the output of this code in a variable (in a vimscript). How can I do this?